# Facebook App Login Cross Domain SecurityError

Tags: facebook, security, cross-domain, cross-site

We have Facebook based web app. It works fine for most browsers but on some of we are getting some errors when a user tries to login. Here is the scenario:

- User clicks on Facebook Login on our WebApp. This is setup using the FB Javascript API.
- Enters credentials
- Page seems to go to the next page but redirects back to the initial login page.

We see the following error in the Javascript console (on Chrome):

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from HTMLIFrameElement: Blocked a frame with origin "https://ourdomain.com/" from accessing a frame with origin https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/.
The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.

We have removed all IFrame access from the login module. However we are still getting the same error. 
Any clue whats going on here? Is there any cross-site HTTPS requests going on here ? How can we detect that what might be causing this?